# How to get Ajax.Net PageMethod to return JSON

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, pagemethods

I am using an AJAX.Net to call an ASP.Net PageMethod, which returns JSON serialized JSON data

```
{"d":"[{\"Fromaddress\":\"testfrom1@test.com\",\"Toaddress\":\"testto1@test.com\"},{\"Fromaddress\":\"testfrom2@test.com\",\"Toaddress\":\"testto2@test.com\"}]"}
```

The Response Header states the content type as

```
"Content-Type   application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

However, the data is just available as a string, and does not seem to be available as JSON data from javascript.  What do I need to do to work with the returned data as JSON from javascript?

Comment: when using `PageMethods.Function()` syntax in javascript, the data will automatically be converted to an object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myData = eval('(' + text + ')');
```

Although this can be a security risk.  Instead you might want to use a JSON parser, such as this one available form https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Then you get notation like:

```
var myData = JSON.parse(text);
```

See http://www.json.org/js.html for more info on this particular parser... I believe there are others to choose from, and that they work very similarly.

Comment: Also - this was a useful link about how to user browsers inbuilt JSON parsing: http://encosia.com/2009/07/07/improving-jquery-json-performance-and-security/